# Android and authenticated HttpPut with JSON body

Tags: android, json, http-put

How do you do write an `HttpPut` request with authentication on Android?

(I'm trying to work around using `HttpURLConnection`, which seems to serious have bugs (at least in Android 2.2) but `GET` works fine. I'd like to send a JSON representation of an array, and I have correct credentials already set using `PasswordAuthentication`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one general solution.

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, this.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, this.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

// Retrieve user credentials.
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
String loginNameString = settings.getString("login_name", null);
String passwordString = settings.getString("password", null);

UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = 
             new UsernamePasswordCredentials(loginNameString, passwordString);
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT);
             client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authScope, 
                                                              credentials);

HttpPut put = new HttpPut(UPLOAD_URL);

try
{
    put.setEntity(new StringEntity(responseJSONArray.toString(),    
                       SERVER_PREFERRED_ENCODING));
    put.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    put.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);

    // 200 type response.
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= HttpStatus.SC_OK &&
    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < HttpStatus.SC_MULTIPLE_CHOICES)
    {
      // Handle OK response etc........
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to have an authentication token. And then just add this line.

```
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + yourToken);
```

Comment: Saved my day!! I was thinking Bearer should be part of the key... moving it to the value saved my hours of debugging!